# Android - How do you redraw a menu button after dynamic modification?

Tags: android, menu

I have a simple pop-up menu with a few buttons. One button starts off disabled. I need to have it become enabled after 1 second. The code below seems to enable the button, but it does not get re-drawn until I click another button on the form.

In the onCreate() method:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 1000, 200);
```

Then in the UpdateTimeTask method:

```
    public void run() {
           ((Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton)).setEnabled(true);
       }
```

When the button is enabled, why doesn't it automatically redraw itself? It appears to stay disabled until I click another button then it suddenly pops up like it's enabled.

"invalidate()" right after the enable line doesn't work either.

Comment: invalidate and then refresh. myButton.refreshDrawableState();

Comment: I tried invalidating the button and then refreshing its drawable state, but no luck. I also tried invalidating the whole RelativeLayout, but then it freezes and nothing is clickable. I tried every invalidate/refresh combination I could think of with the button and layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Runnable instead of a Timer. This article was a huge help:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

I didn't have to use invalidate or refreshDrawableState since it's all done on the same UI thread.